# I would like to use 3 main and one conditional components for my pages in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, frontend, tailwind-css

I am building a react app with tailwind css . I would like to use 3 main required components for all pages (Navbar,Left Part and Right Part) , also I would like to use 1 conditional component which change each page (Middle Part of Website)

[This is my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM9gv.jpg) . Red ones is my main components that I would like to use all pages , blue one is up to pages ( For example "/" , "/home" , "/dashboard" etc ...)

Could u help me about it ? Is it possible ? Thanks for help .

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className="flex justify-between max-w-8xl sm:px-2 md:px-4">
        <Left/>
        <Middle/> // This will be "/" routes
        <Right/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my app.js . I wrote this code but it did not work (tailwind style) clearly. Also I dont know it is true or not .

Comment: not sure why this was closed. Because its a new user? the link to answer is more complex than what the OP is asking.